# NullPointerException error issue

Tags: java, exception

The following code gives me a NullPointerException. I do not know why it throws this error at me and I cannot seem to find a post that has a similar issue as mine. Any help is appreciated.

```
 public class App5 {
  public void main (String[] args) {
    int result = 0;
    System.out.println(result);
  }
}
```

The error trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at      
edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.JavacCompiler.runCommand(JavacCompiler.java:272)
```

Comment: `public static void main()` ?

Comment: It doesn't throw error *at you*. No, it's nothing personal! Follow [this link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/) to understand *why*.

Comment: @skuntsel Maybe it is. You can't say for certain.

Answer (score 3):

You need to declare your entry point as:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

not:

```
public void main(String[] args)
```

The exception is invoked because the JVM searches for an entry point, but doesn't find one.